# I cannot publish an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, publishing, asp.net-core-3.0

The project was created at ASP. I can’t post. Below screenshots of errors and code
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAjao.png)
[WEB.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfePe.png)

Comment: Can you add screenshot? Can you paste errors, or stacktrace?

Comment: Please provide your output messages or logs

Comment: `bin\Debug` is a red flag. You are supposed to point it to the output folder of `dotnet publish`, not `dotnet build`.